# How to start an RTSP connection using android app?

Tags: android, rtsp

How can I start an RTSP connection using android app? Is there any API or method with which we can start and establish RTSP connection?

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spex66/RTSP-Camera-for-Android

This might help you.It is basically a Live Streaming app based on RTSP protocol and RTSP connection between Android Phone to a PC on the same wifi!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pedroSG94/RootEncoder

This library help you to establish connection.It support Java and Kotlin as well it's well maintained.

RootEncoder (rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java) is a stream encoder to push video/audio to media servers using protocols RTMP, RTSP and SRT with all code written in Java/Kotlin.